# Javascript OOP - abstraction (asking for example), encapsulation (grouping together properties/methods or keeping state private?), polymorphism

Tags: javascript, oop

I know there are tons of oop posts on here as well as many blogs etc. I'm not posting this because im too lazy to read other posts, I probably read about 100 and still have some questions as many just state things but dont explain them much or certain things have contradicting answers and it would be great if I could get clear answers!

**Encapsulation**
There are posts that say yes to that because they define it as grouping together properties and functions. If that would be the definition, I totally get why javascript supports encapsulation. However, there also posts about keeping members private. As I understand (dont know java) but in Java thats the concept - you cannot access properties without methods (so only methods can access them) plus you actually have 'private/public' keywords to keep things private.

before ES6 :
Its possible:

```
  function A (name) {
    var name = name;
    this.getName = function () {
      return name;
    }
  }
  var a = new A("mike");
  a.getName() //accesses name
  a.name //does not --> results in undefined
```

In es6 its not really possible, because you you would have to add the method accessing the property inside the constructor, which you wouldnt do

```
  class A {
    constructor(name) {
    var name = name;
      this.getName = () => {
        return name;         // only like this could you have var ... 
      }
    }
  }
```

So my question:
1. What is encapsulation ? Is it about grouping methods/properties or is it about keeping members private (which wouldnt be possible in es6 and before es6 not by default)?

**Abstraction**
" hiding internal implementation details. It should only reveal operations relevant for the other objects "

I would imagine for example jquery methods to use abstraction and you dont see their inner implemantion, 'just use' them. Could someone please explain and provide an example im vanilla js what abstraction is and if javascript actually makes use of that?

**polymorphism**

"designing objects to share behaviors and to be able to override shared behaviors with specific ones"

- overriding
- overloading

Many posts/blogs say polymorphism is NOT used in javascript, but..
Overloading is without argument not possible in javascript. Overriding of methods is?! I can have a parent class and a child class having the same function (same name) doing different things. Is that what you understand under overriding? Also, sharing behaviors is def. possible but only with inheritance.
Is there a way to share behaviors without inheritance, but only with making use of polymorphism? Im generally confused what exactly polymorphism is after reading for a while..

**Inheritance**
Inheritance is def. supported by js.
I just want to double check about es6 classes that I get it right (i have no experience with java etc).
The difference is that js uses prototypical inheritance and not classical as java etc. The difference is that when I create a new instance/=object from my es6 class, it links to properties/methods of the class that I use to initialize new objects, while in classical inheritance, the engine copies the properties/methods from that class. s that correct? Could someone please explain the difference - resulting - from that difference?

Comment: Please ask a single question per post only.

Comment: "*What is encapsulation?*" is too broad to be answered on SO. If you e.g. read the Wikipedia article, you will also notice that there are multiple different definitions - you already seemed to have picked that up from the blogs. There is no single standards body that can make an official definition.

Comment: Same for [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). And one could definitely say that duck-typing is a form of polymorphism.

Comment: "*in classical inheritance, the engine copies the properties/methods from that class.*" - nope. Even there, an instance has a pointer to the class where its behaviour can be found. The most fundamental difference is that in class-based OOP the "class" is not a first-class value, not a plain object like anything else, and that usually methods and static constants etc. are more clearly distinguished from data properties.

Comment: I put all questions into one question as they all about OOP. Nothing you said answers my questions (too broad to be answered isnt really helpful), so still if anyone can tell me answer my questions about OOP in Javascript, it would be great.

Comment: Regarding encapsulation, I said that there is no definite answer. This question can't be answered. Everything you read is right, even if they use (or assume) conflicting definitions of the term.